# Looping until end of String C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string (input is performed by user) which has an expression to be checked against a regex pattern matcher.

I wish to loop through the String until EOF. I was thinking of using `input.Length` but then I don't know how to continue to compare the number. If the whole string is correct against the pattern then it returns TRUE, otherwise FALSE. This is where I arrived till now.

```
private void checkInput (String input)
{
    {
        String acceptedInput = "(?=\\()|(?<=\\)\\d)";

        // Need a loop until End of String

        // (while ?)
        {
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, acceptedInput))
            {
                outputDialog.AppendText("Correct");
            }

            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do it please?

Thank you

Comment: *"I wish to loop through the String"* or you need to loop though each character?

Comment: What I mostly needed was to check the whole string, as in another method, I need to check whether it is true (the bool return) to see whether to proceed or show an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop over each char in a string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringVariable.Length; i++)
{
    char x = stringVariable[i]; //is the i'th character of the string
}
```

But that approach makes no sense if your using RegEx, which generally work on entire strings.

Maybe explain what your trying to achieve?

Comment: Stringvariable is the string variable :) input in my case. Thanks Cjb110 Worked like a charm

Comment: cjb110, checkInput is a method, which checks whether the patter is good. it then returns TRUE or FALSE (I edited the "public void to public bool" in my program. If it returns true, then it can continue with what it was doing. otherwise halts the program

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

i.e.

```
    char[] array = input.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {       
        var letter = array[i];//here is the individual character
    }
```

Comment: For completeness of this, ToCharArray has created a copy which your unlikely to need if your just doing reads.

Comment: @cjb110: didn't knew I can access directly `string[index]` :)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to loop:

```
string toAvoid = "$%&#";
if (input.IndexOfAny(toAvoid.ToCharArray()) != -1)
{
  // the input contains forbidden characters
}
```